# Laravel handling special characters strangely after calling orderBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Does anyone know why Laravel handles special characters like ä and ö like they are a and o after calling orderBy? How could I get rid of this annoying behavior?

Comment: Please post some code. It will help us finding solution

Comment: This is often the expected behaviour, the collation of your field determines the order of your query.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. You have to set your table collation to something that can be recognized by your MySQL-database.

[image]

To swedish in your case

[image]

From the command line

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;
```